# Search not working Magento 1.9 rwd theme

Tags: magento, search, magento-1.9

I am using magento RWD theme for my project and have made some customization in the theme.

But my search is not working in it.

Few things I have tried are:-

1. Reindexing data.
2. Flush magento cache.
3. Went to System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search and set Search Type to Combine (Like and Fulltext)
4. `http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/magento-search-not-working`

All are of no avail.
I have created a gist of required files.
https://gist.github.com/bhargavmehta/4aee123a93e07b4db60c

Can Anyone point out the error?

Comment: could you elaborate on the result of a search?  is it returning no products or are you getting a blank screen?  could you also post the url you reach when you perform a search (remove your domain name).

Comment: I was getting no search results found for that product.
I just solved the issue. By removing the comment in block left_first in catalogsearch.xml
But a new issue has started left nav is now showing up want to remove that shop by categories.
[link](http://infigic.com/ds4u/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out many solutions to it and created a blog to how I solved this issue.

You can find solutions here at [Magento Search solution](http://www.infigic.com/magento-search-not-working/)

Comment: Overview of the article (in case of link rot): clear Magento caches, reindex, try the normal Magento theme, check product attributes are searchable, check the search settings.